What are the uses of bound charge?
From Introduction to Electrodynamics, D. J. Griffiths (fourth edition), I think I have grasped the notion of bound charges—that they appear on the surface of a polarised dielectric.
But what is the significance of these charges? Are they there simply to give the electric field a direction, or is there some other reason? Can they tell us more about the configuration of a system?

Bound charges are charges that are, in a specific sense, fixed to the material. They are not free to move around as the free charges are. One reason to split the charge distribution in free and bound charges is because it is often easier to describe the free charge, but hard to describe the bound charge. Hence, it is useful to have expressions that allow us to compute the electromagnetic fields only in terms of the free charges—these are the Maxwell equations in a medium, also known as the macroscopic Maxwell equations.
Wald's Advanced Classical Electromagnetism has a nice discussion of electrostatics in media on Chap. 3. In short, there he shows that the bounded charge density (which he calls polarization charge density) is caused by the microscopic dipole contributions to the averaged (macroscopic) charge density. Hence, the bounded charges are physically caused by slight displacements of charges that are bound to the material. You get a macroscopic charge density which is caused by charges which, microscopically, are not allowed to move freely throughout the material.

I understand the irony in recommending a book called Advanced Classical Electromagnetism to a question about Introduction to Electrodynamics

Thank you for your answer, @Nickolas-Alves. But the question is more in the vein of "What's useful about bound charges?" That is, why are they significant? For example, integrate the surface charge density and you will find the total charge on the surface. What effect do similar manipulations, for example, have on bound charges?

@DanielFBest I would say their usefulness doesn't like on them, but on the free charges. It is easier to work with free charges, so we define bound charges to get rid of them

@Nickolas-Alvez, oh okay, I understand. That's very useful information, thank you.
